# getting result in short running celery task (Django)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, celery

What is the best way to implement getting result in short running celery task (3-7 seconds) ?

For now i use this method below.

- User clicks button which send request to api - api triggers celery task and returns `task_id`
- Then we are checking result of `task_id` via Ajax

UPDATE: question should be closed at it has no difference between getting result from long running task .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule (with all background tasks, not just Celery/Django) that's actually your best bet. The same pattern emerges

- User makes HTTP request
- Server kicks off background service (either through Celergy, some other async. service, or even through a command line execution (<- don't do that if you can avoid it)) and returns some form of identifier
- User agent makes new HTTP request to get information about state of new service/process.

You should check out [long polling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944644/how-to-display-html-to-the-browser-incrementally-over-a-long-period-of-time)